# Congiuntivo o indicativo in questa frase

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood

Quale tra queste due scelte è la forma corretta, quella con l'indicativo oppure quella con il congiuntivo?

1. Sì, questo l’ho capito, per questo ti ho chiesto se eri disponibile dopo.
2. Sì, questo l’ho capito, per questo ti ho chiesto se fossi  disponibile dopo.

Comment: Benvenuta su ItalianSE! Potresti arricchire la tua domanda inserendo qualche informazione in più?

Comment: Lo so che suona orrendamente paternalistico, ma che qualcuno che ha una padronanza non raffinatissima dell'ortografia e della punteggiatura si ponga questi problemi mi sembra un segno del fatto che il congiuntivo è, dopo tutto, ancora ben vivo.

Comment: @DaG La morte del congiuntivo è spesso sopravvalutata, ma le interrogative indirette sono purtroppo uno dei posti dove è più reale. È un vero peccato (anche perché rimpiazza una regola semplice e chiara con una ambigua e complicata), ma più di cercare di usarlo correttamente io non so che fare.

Answer (score 5):

La subordinata in questione "...se fossi/eri disponibile dopo" è un'interrogativa indiretta. Le regole grammaticali "classiche" raccomandano che nelle interrogative indirette si usi sempre il congiuntivo, per cui la versione corretta dovrebbe essere:

> Sì, questo l'ho capito, per questo ti ho chiesto se fossi disponibile dopo

Ahimè l'uso ha fatto sì che nelle interrogative indirette si diffonda sempre di più l'indicativo, specialmente quando si tratta di una domanda di cui si conosce già la risposta. Questa pratica, originaria della lingua parlata, si sta spargendo un po' anche nella lingua scritta e finanche in registri relativamente alti.

Il mio consiglio personale è di usare sempre il congiuntivo (che è sempre corretto), ma di essere tolleranti quando si sente usare l'indicativo perché la grammatica è viva, che ci piaccia o che non ci piaccia.

Comment: A seconda del contesto, anche *saresti stato* potrebbe essere adoperato.

Comment: @egreg Certo, non volevo spendere troppo tempo sulla *consecutio temporum*, ma il condizionale passato ricopre, come solito, il ruolo del (non esistente) congiuntivo futuro anteriore